# Prove $\binom{n+2}{k+2} = \binom{n}{k+2} + 2\binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

I have to prove the following statement

$$\binom{n+2}{k+2} = \binom{n}{k+2} + 2\binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}$$

I know, I have to use the following fact

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$$

but I can't seem to figure out how. Some hints would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: @downvoter Is there anyway I can improve the post? Thanks

Comment: I did not down vote but your body does not show any effort except writing that known formula.... your previous question has same problem... it would look good if you could realize that gap..

Comment: I don't have any problem showing effort; I have asked numerous questions where I have shown plenty of effort. In this case and the previous case, the problem is: I don't know where to start - at all. Hence, "some hints would be appreciated". I'm not asking for a solution at all. I just need a place to get started because I don't know how.

Comment: @gekkostate: I'm sorry, but this question as posted seems just ridiculous to me. That's all I can say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kept in mind the recursive characteristics of the Pascal triangle to do this one, together with the relation you had to consider:

$$\binom{n+2}{k+2} = {\color{red}{\binom{n+1}{k+2}}} + {\color{blue}{\binom{n+1}{k+1}}} \\
= {\color{red}{\binom{n}{k+2} + \binom{n}{k+1}}}  + {\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}}}\\
={\color{red}{\binom{n}{k+2}}} + {\color{purple}{2\binom{n}{k+1}}} + {\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}}}$$

(The one in the middle is purple because red plus blue equals purple)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't have to use that formula.
Consider a set of $n+2$ elements, where $a$, $b$ are two of those elements.

The number of all $k+2$ element subsets is $\binom{n+2}{k+2}$. But you can also compute it by considering the number of subsets not containing $a$ and $b$ which is $\binom n{k+2}$, subsets containing $a$, but not $b$ or $b$, but not $a$, each of which is $\binom n{k+1}$ and the number of subsets containing both $a$ and $b$ which is $\binom nk$.

So $\displaystyle\binom{n+2}{k+2}=\binom n{k+2}+2\binom n{k+1}+\binom nk$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is just a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), which says

$${m+n \choose r}=\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k},\qquad m,n,r\in\mathbb{N}_0.$$

The result you're looking for occurs when $m=2$, and there are several proofs on the linked wiki page.